# How can I fix Error code 1241 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT c.Staff_no, c.Start_datetime, c.End_datetime, s.First_name, s.Profession, s.Department, s.Gender
 FROM duty_roster_1501003f c, staff_1501003f s where c.Staff_no = s.Staff_no IN
 (SELECT Staff_no, Start_datetime, End_datetime FROM duty_roster_1501003f WHERE Remarks = 'overtime' ORDER BY staff_no);
```

The error code says Operand should contain 1 column(s). What should i do to fix it?

Comment: You cannot select more than one column in sub-query. So try to get result by joining the different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you say:

```
...  WHERE c.Staff_no = s.Staff_no IN (SELECT Staff_no, Start_datetime, End_datetime FROM duty_roster_1501003f WHERE Remarks = 'overtime' ORDER BY staff_no);
```

That is not valid.  Maybe you want:

```
...  WHERE c.Staff_no = s.Staff_no AND c.Staff_no IN
      (SELECT Staff_no FROM duty_roster_1501003f WHERE Remarks = 'overtime')
```

A select for an `IN` can only return 1 column *(what would you have it do with the other columns?)*

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an AND/OR and a field name before IN

WHERE
c.Staff_no = s.Staff_no
**AND someField** IN (Subquery)

Also, the subquery should return only one field, and not 3 as you're returning now.